# Bindvars in golangs sqlx.DB.Select() statement requires 0 parameters

Tags: go, sqlx, pq

I'm using SQLX and PQ to query an SQL database with PostGress. I'm using the function Select from SQLX with bindvars but PQ panics with

> pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0.

```
 query = `
    SELECT 
        count(*) AS count 
    FROM 
        ledger 
    WHERE 
        enterprise_id=($1)
 `
 var stat singleStat

 err = db.Select(&stat, query, enterpriseID)
```

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the brackets?

Comment: I've tried with `enterprise_id=$1` but same outcome

Comment: Apparently this was a an issue with the pq driver and it's interaction with crate (the db I'm using). Using the go-crate driver for golang fixes the issue but go-crate doesn't look that is being maintained

Answer (score 1):

If anyone gets to here, I found out the answer by digging a bit on the pq source code. 
To use prepared parameters with Crate, it requires driver to send the parameters as binary before preparing the statement; answering with the types of the parameters.

To accomplish this, add 'binary_parameters=yes' to your connection string. Like:

> "user=crate dbname=test binary_parameters=yes"